# Trying to make an icon open whatsApp on click with <a> Tag. it's just refreshing page

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to make on a Wordpress site, an html  tag to open whatsApp on click

here is the code

```
<a href="https://wa.me/+972000000000">Whatsapp</a>
```

But when i click on the image that have the code it's just refreshing the page instead on opening WhatsApp.

[here is display and position setting on the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKoCS.png)

[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsMKD.png)

Comment: Add target attribute to this `<a href="https://wa.me/+972000000000" target="_blank">Whatsapp</a>`

Answer (score 0):

> target="_blank"

```
<a href="https://wa.me/+972000000000" target="_blank">Whatsapp</a>
```

**Or**

*Go to link settings > check Open In new Window Option*

[image]

Comment: Tried to mark " Open in new window " but when i click the whatsApp icon it's just refresh create a new tab with the home page

Answer (score 0):

According to the instructions at [Whatsapp's Help Center (FAQ)](https://faq.whatsapp.com/5913398998672934/?helpref=uf_share) you have formatted the number wrong.

> Use `https://wa.me/<number>` where the `<number>` is a full phone number in
> international format. **Omit any zeroes, brackets, or dashes** when adding
> the phone number in international format. Examples: Use:
> https://wa.me/1XXXXXXXXXX Don't use: https://wa.me/+001-(XXX)XXXXXXX

Just remove the '+' before the number.

e.g. `<a href="https://wa.me/972000000000">Whatsapp</a>`